# Problem with Media Device(MTP) when connect to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, android, mtp, alcatel

I used to transfer files from pc to mobile using MTP option. but suddenly two days back i am unable to connect my mobile. I clicked on MTP option in mobile but i didn't get any device in ubuntu. i tried many time. I am not figured out whats problem.can you please suggest some troubleshooting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *This is often more about MTP on the mobile (smartphone/tablet), than Ubuntu.* **What version of Android are you using?** Have you recently updated either the mobile or PC?

Answer (score 0):

MTP needs unlocked phone.

Unlock the lockscreen, and If mtpfs and gvfs installed It will work well.

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs gvfs
```